# How do I reliably convert some Pinia state to local component state

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, pinia

In my Nuxt app I have a page to edit the user profile, which is data that is kept in a Pinia store. Here's the basics of that store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { Database } from '~~/types/supabase'

interface Profile {
    id: string
    important_field: number | null
}

interface State {
    profile: Profile | null
}

export const useStore = defineStore('main', {
    state: (): State => {
        return {
            profile: null
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async getProfile() {
            const { data: profile, error } = await useSupabaseClient<Database>().from('profiles').select().limit(1).single()
            if (profile) {
                this.profile = profile
            }
        },
        async updateProfile(profile: Profile) {
            this.profile = profile
            const { error } = await useSupabaseClient<Database>()
                .from('profiles')
                .update(profile)
                .eq('id', profile.id)
        }
    },
})
```

When `app.vue` is booted the `getProfile` method is called.

Now, when I go to the `/profile` page I don't want to be able to reactively adjust `important_field`. As the name suggests, the field is important to the rest of the apps functionality, so I'd like the user to be able to adjust it and then click on a save button to store it back to Pinia.

To do this, I thought I could copy the profile state into a local reactive variable in my profile page component, modify that, and then send it back to the store's `updateProfile` method:

```
const store = useStore()
const profile = reactive({...store.profile})
```

However, when I load the `/profiles` page the problem arises that Pinia has not yet been installed, so `store.profile` is null and my local `profile` variable never gets the data that gets fetched from the server and update to the Pinia store. Even putting the above in `onMounted` does not work: the component mounts before Pinia is installed and so the local profile variable stays "blank".

I have bodged together a solution, that works, but it's hacky as anything.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStore } from '~~/stores'
import { Database } from '~~/types/supabase'
type Profile = Database['public']['Tables']['profiles']['Row']

const store = useStore()
const profile: Profile = reactive({ id: '', important_field: 0 })

store.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    if (profile.id === '' && state.profile !== null) {
        profile.id = state.profile.id
        profile.important_field = state.profile.important_field
    }
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Profile
    <div v-if="profile">
        <label for="">
            Important Field
            <input type="number" v-model="profile.important_field">
        </label>
    </div>
    <button @click="store.updateProfile(profile)">Save</button>
    <br>
  </div>
</template>
```

This seems clunky, and I feel I am missing a better way to do this.

**Is there a better solution to grabbing state from a Pinia store, locally adjusting it, and then sending it back to the store?**

Answer (score 0):

Solving problem without Pinia using Nuxt already built in variable state management `useState()`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { data: profile, error } = await useSupabaseClient<Database>().from('profiles').select().limit(1).single()
const profileData = reactive({...profile})
useState('profile', () => profile) // Assigning variable to global variable state management already inside Nuxt. No need any Pinia!
</script>
```

Saving data:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
// Getting global variable to local, so you can change it without changing original one.
const profile = toReactive(useState('profile'))

function update() {
useSupabaseClient<Database>()
                .from('profiles')
                .update(profile)
                .eq('id', profile.id)
useState('profile').value = profile
}
</script>
```

`useState()` works on server and client. If you need some user credential to get user data. Wrap component in: `<ClientOnly><UserProfile></UserProfile></ClientOnly>` so component will be only rendered on client side and there won't be an issue.